# Installer hangs, Ubiquity error

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, ubiquity

I have an HP Ultrabook 4 that currently contains some version of Windows (I think Windows 8), and I'm trying to completely replace it with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have a bootable USB stick that runs fine on the machine. When I try to install from the stick, I eventually get to the Installation Type screen, which displays an empty partition list; the New Partition Table button is grayed out. (Note that this is the first Installation Type screen I see; I never get the screen offering me the option to erase the disk and install.) If I press "+", either just crashes silently or I get a message about an internal error involving Ubiquity. Any suggestions?

By the way, related or not, on the initial screen, when selecting a language, I don't get the graphics on the right side containing large buttons asking about live vs install (the buttons that are shown on the Ubuntu pages relating to installation) - that part of the window is just blank.

Screenshots of parted and lsblk are below:
[image]
[image]